# How does the ring of algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$ depend on $D\mod 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $O_K$ be the ring of algebraic integers inside of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$. Why is it that when $D \equiv 2, 3 \mod 4$ that $O_K = \{x + y\sqrt{D} : x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and that when $D \equiv 1 \mod 4$ that $O_K = \{x + y\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{D}}{2}\right) : x, y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}, a,b, b^2-4c \in \Bbb{Z},  b^2-4ac=m^2 D$

Comment: @reuns I am having trouble seeing the connection.

Comment: algebraic integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt D]$ are roots of $x^2+bx+c=0$ where $b$ and $c$ are integers (leading coefficient is $1$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{D}$ then is given by 
$$
(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))=x^2-2ax+(a^2-b^2D),
$$
where $\sigma(a+b\sqrt{D})=a-b\sqrt{D}$. 
The coefficients are integers if and only if the above conditions are met. The claim follows now from your previous (deleted) question.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!