# Number Theory theorem regarding ring of integers in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Here is the theorem that I need to prove

> For $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$ we have
>
> $$\begin{align}O_K = \begin{cases} 
>       \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}] & D \equiv 2, 3 \mod 4\\
>       \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{D}}{2}\right] & D \equiv 1 \mod 4
>    \end{cases}
> \end{align}$$

The theorem we need to use is this one that can be found in any generic number theory textbook.

> an element $\alpha\in K$ is an algebraic integer if and only if its minimal polynomial has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried many avenues of attack but it is extremely hard to prove. How do I prove it?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191240/how-does-the-ring-of-algebraic-integers-in-mathbbq-sqrtd-depend-on-d-m/3191265#3191265)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner the answer kind of gave me what I already knew but knowing it doesn't even get me to 10% of where I need to go.

Comment: Let $\alpha=p+q\sqrt D$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Q$; what is its minimal polynomial?  how to ensure its coefficients are in $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bullet$ Let $d \equiv 1 \mod 4.$

Let $A=x+y\sqrt{d} \in \mathcal O_K$ be arbitrary. We have

$(A-x)^2 - dy^2 = 0$. Expanding,

$A^2 -2xA +x^2 - dy^2 = 0$.

Now we use the fact that $m_A(x)$, the minimal polynomial of $A$, must be in $\Bbb Z[x]$: we must have $x=\frac{r}{2}$ for some $r \in \Bbb Z$.

Since $x^2 - dy^2  \in \Bbb Z$ too, we must have $y = \frac{s}{2}$.

So $x^2 - dy^2 = \frac{r^2}{4} -d\frac{s^2}{4}$.

This implies $r^2 - ds^2 \equiv r^2 - s^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$.

So $r \equiv s \mod 2$, i.e. $r=s+2t$.

Putting this together, $A=\frac{r}{2} + \frac{s}{2}\sqrt{d} = t+s\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ as required, showing that $\mathcal O_K = \Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$.

$\bullet$ Now assume $d \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

We can repeat the above argument, arriving at

$r^2 +2s^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$.

The only solution is $(r, s) = (0, 0) \mod 4$, so in fact $x, y \in \Bbb Z$ and $\mathcal O_K = \Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$.

$\bullet$ For $d \equiv 3 \mod 4$ we have to consider $r^2 + s^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and we come to the same conclusion as for $d=2$.

Comment: $m_A$ is a free variable. How did you introduce it?

Comment: That's supposed to be the minimal polynomial of $A$, I'll edit it.

Comment: Where in your proof did you use the assumption that $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$?

Comment: @ErotemeObelus when reducing the first congruence: $r^2-ds^2 \equiv r^2 - s^2$ since $d \equiv 1$.

Comment: I don't understand why $r^2 - s^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4 \Rightarrow r \equiv s \mod 2$ and why $r^2 + 2s^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4 \Rightarrow (r, s) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: @ErotemeObelus For the first statement, prove its converse: if two numbers differ $\mod 2$, their squares can‘t agree $\mod 4$. For the second statement, notice that a square $\mod 4$ must be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Lukas I figured out your proof. It's the simplest one on here. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha=p+q\sqrt D$ with $p,q\in\mathbb Q$.  The other root of its minimal polynomial is $\bar \alpha=p-q\sqrt D.$

The minimal polynomial is $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha)=x^2-(\alpha+\bar\alpha)x+\alpha\bar\alpha=x^2-2px+(p^2-q^2D).  $

For $-2p$ to be an integer, say $-m$, $p=m/2$, where $m \in \mathbb Z$.

For $p^2-q^2D$ to be an integer, say $n$, this means also $q=l/2$ for some $l \in \mathbb Z$.

So $p^2-q^2D=(\frac m 2)^2-(\frac l 2)^2D$ is an integer so $m^2-l^2D$ is a multiple of $4$.

Modulo $4$, $m^2$ and $l^2$ could be $\equiv0$ or $1$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of approaches depending on how much you assume. Assuming one only knows traces and norms and your theorem, this should be a 'low brow' approach that gets there without any other knowledge assumptions.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, where $d\neq 1$ is a squarefree integer. We want to find $\mathcal{O}_K$. If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{d} \in \mathcal{O}_K$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, we know that $\text{Nm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha),\text{Tr}_{K/Q}(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $a^2-db^2,2a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Multiplying $a^2-db^2$ by 4, we obtain $(2a)^2-d(2b)^2,2a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, $2\mathcal{O}_K \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]=\{a+b\sqrt{d} \colon a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then we have an inclusion of abelian groups
    $$
 \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \subseteq \dfrac{1}{2}\, \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]
 $$
The quotient $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a group of order 4 with coset representatives: 0, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}$, and $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$.

In order to determine $\mathcal{O}_K$, we need to determine which of these representatives are algebraic integers. Clearly, $0 \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathcal{O}_K$. The minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}$ is $x^2 - \frac{d}{4}$---which is not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as $d$ is square free. Hence, $\frac{\sqrt{d}}{4} \notin \mathcal{O}_K$. Finally, the minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ is
    $$
 \left(x - \dfrac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right) \left(x - \dfrac{1-\sqrt{d}}{2}\right)= x^2-x+ \dfrac{1-d}{4}.
 $$
Then $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ has minimal polynomial $p_\alpha(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. [That is, $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2} \in \mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$.] Therefore,
    $$
 \mathcal{O}_K=
 \begin{cases}
 \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}], & d \not\equiv 1 \mod 4 \\
 \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right], & d \equiv 1 \mod 4.
 \end{cases}
 $$

Comment: What’s the “high brow” approach?

Comment: Nice proof (+1). Note that you could rephrase this to even avoid mention of trace and norm by simply observing that the product and sum of the roots are coefficients of the integer monic minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a proof in many number theory textbooks. In Hardy and Wright's classic *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, for instance, its Theorem 238 on [p.207](https://archive.org/details/Hardy_and_Wright_-_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers/page/n221).

Comment: Not constructive. Puts down the person who asked the question.

Comment: @ErotemeObelus. My apologies.  I had no intention of putting you down, although I can see why you might have been offended by my original wording, which I have now modified.