# Characterization of integers of Quadratic Fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a square-free integer, and consider the quadratic number field $k=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$; prove that $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $a \equiv b \equiv 1/2 \bmod \mathbb{Z}$.

$\Leftarrow$ is easy, but I know not how to do $\Rightarrow$.

This exercise is interesting because shows

1. If $n \not \equiv 1 \bmod \,4$ then $O_k=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$
2. If $n \equiv 1 \bmod \, 4$ then $O_k=\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{n})/2]$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197683/number-theory-theorem-regarding-ring-of-integers-in-mathbbq-sqrtd)

Comment: Apply the definition of integral

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha=a+b\sqrt n$ is integral means $\alpha$ is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients:  $(x-(a+b\sqrt n))(x-(a-b\sqrt n))=x^2-2ax+(a^2-nb^2)$, so $2a$ and $a^2-nb^2$ are integers.  Can you take it from here?  Note that $0$ and $1$ are the quadratic residues modulo $4.  $

Comment: Ok, then $n(2b)^2=(2a^2)-4(a^2-nb^2)$ is integer thus  since $n$ is quare-free $2b$ is also.

Comment: And I can do some similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3197712/504126. Thank you!