# Integral basis discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-22})$. Prove that $\{1,\sqrt{-22}\}$ is an integral basis for the ring of integers $O_K$.

Attempt: A typical element of $K$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt{-22}$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. The minimum polynomial of $\sqrt{-22}$ is $x^2+22$, with roots $\pm\sqrt{-22}$. Hence, the two conjugation maps are as follows:

\begin{equation}
\sigma_1(a+b\sqrt{-22})=a+b\sqrt{-22}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sigma_2(a+b\sqrt{-22})=a-b\sqrt{-22}
\end{equation}

The discriminant of this candidate integral basis is
\begin{equation}
\Delta[1,\sqrt{-22}]=\begin{vmatrix}1&\sqrt{-22}\\1&-\sqrt{-22}\end{vmatrix}^2=-88,
\end{equation}
which is not squarefree. If it were to be squarefree, we would be done, as then our candidate integral basis would indeed be an integral basis. But as it is not squarefree, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The question title has nothing to do with the content!

Comment: A cheap trick is that the discriminant of an integral basis is always an integer congruent to 0 or 1 mod 4 (Stickelberger's little theorem). The only nontrivial square dividing -88 is 4, so if $[1, \sqrt{-22}]$ isn't an integral basis, then the discriminant would have to be -88 / 4 = -22, which is impossible since -22 = 2 mod 4. So it must be a basis.

Comment: It follows directly from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191240/how-does-the-ring-of-algebraic-integers-in-mathbbq-sqrtd-depend-on-d-m?noredirect=1&lq=1), since $-22\equiv 2\bmod 4$. An integral basis then is $\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For quadratic extensions $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ ($d$ squarefree), it is a well known result that the integral basis can be taken as $1,\alpha$ where $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ if $d\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $\alpha=\sqrt{d}$ otherwise.